# Opencv Cascade classification instead of detection

Tags: python, c++, opencv, haar-classifier

I have trained my classifiers by using Cascade classification from opencv for object classification.

I have three classes and I have got three *.xml files.

I know one region of the image must be one of the three classes.

However by using opencv, only detectMultiScale function is provided, I must scan the image (or ROI) to find all possible objects in it.

Is there method to classify whether one image(or roi) is matching a specified object or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From your question I understand that you want to classify three separate ROIs of an image. You might want to create three crops for the defined ROIs:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("full_image.png")
crop_img1 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
#create crop_img2 and crop_img3 analogously
```

And apply a classifier on each of the three cropped images.

Comment: It's worth adding that ROI doesn't mean copying data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not about how to extract an ROI, but how to use Cascade Haar classifier to classify whether an ROI belongs to a class or not. I will try to improve my description also.

Comment: Yes, I make the assumption that you already know the three ROIs (that is, the coordinates `y`, `x`  as well as height and width `w`, `h` of each region).
Do I understand correctly from your comment that you want to rather know how to use the built-in classifier in general?

Comment: Generally, I would like to point out the difference between _classification_ and _detection_. The task you want to perform is _classification_ of an image (an ROI would also be an image). Classification would be the assignment of one single class label to such picture. OpenCV's `detectMultiScale` method is used for _detection_, that is the *localization of zero or more object bounding boxes* in an image (for example, all human faces in a given input image).